# Find the mass of a solid bounded by the surfaces (triple integral)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the mass of a solid bounded by the surfaces: $z=4-x$, $z=0$, $y=0$, $y=4$ & $x=0$ with density x at $(x,y,z)$

I'm not sure how to find the limits of integration for $x$.

I know this is a triple integral that is set up like this:

$$\int^?_?\int^{4}_{0}\int^{4-x}_{0}x\;dz\;dy\;dx$$

Hints?

After looking at it further, I assume it would be:

$$\int^4_0\int^{4}_{0}\int^{4-x}_{0}x\;dz\;dy\;dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. The volume is just the box [0,4][0,4] bounded above by $z=4-x$.

Another way to think of it is: You are given the $y$ and $z$ bounds, and one of the $x$ bounds. To get the other $x$ bound, plug $z=0$ (lower $z$ bound) in $z=4-x$ and solve for $x$.